# float div to left of parent div not working

Tags: html, css

With my current code, how do I make the purple div stick to the left side of the green div? I tried `float:left` which didn't work. I got close when adding   `position:absolute; and  left:50%;` to my purple div class but when the screen resized the div fell off screen. Is there a quick way to float the purple div to the left of the green one so it's not in the center?

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  background-color:pink;
  height:91%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

#right{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display:flex;
}

#logo {
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:calc(80vh - 25px);
  background-color:purple;

}
#logo:before {
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the purple box to be all the way to the left end of the screen or to the right of the blue box?

Comment: @koder613 right of the blue box, so its only stuck to the left side of the green div

Comment: Do you need the `#logo` div to be in the `#right` div?

Comment: @koder613 yes needs to stay in right div

Comment: Check my answer, Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  background-color:pink;
  height:91%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

#right{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display:flex;
}

#logo {
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width:calc(80vh - 25px);
  background-color:purple;

}
#logo:before {
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not keep the purple square a square (the aspect ratio 1:1)

Comment: I think you can check my answer is right. :)

Comment: Yes 100%, so instead of Left:0 i needed margin-left:0; awesome. thanks!